# Artin reciprocity and 1-dimensional representations

Tags: number-theory, class-field-theory

The usual formulation of Artin reciprocity (for example in Neukirch or Lang's book on algebraic number theory), applied to L-funcions, says that for an irreducible character $\chi$ of an **abelian** extension,
$$L(\chi,s)=L(\tilde{\chi},s)$$
where $\tilde{\chi}$ is a Grobencharakter, and the L-series on the right is an abelian (Hecke) L-funcion.

But another formulation is that Artin reciprocity implies the equality above for **all 1-dimensional characters**.

How does one prove this?

I'm sure this is an easy consequence, but I don't understand it. It is easy to see that:

> abelian extension $\to$ 1-dimensional character

But the converse is not true, there are plenty of 1-dimensional characters of non-abelian extensions.

Comment: A one-dimensional character of a finite group $G$ is a homomorphism $G \rightarrow \mathbf C^\times$, so it factors through a homomorphism $G' \rightarrow \mathbf C^\times$ where $G' = G/[G,G]$ is the abelianization of $G$.  Thus any one-dim. char. of a finite group is a one-dim. character of this (maximal) abelian quotient of the group, and if $G = {\rm Gal}(E/F)$ then this quotient group is ${\rm Gal}(K/F)$ for some field $K$ between $E$ and $F$ that is in fact the maximal abelian extension of $F$ inside $E$.